# How do I programmatically remove a ckeditor button based on a user permission

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Without creating a whole new text format and ckeditor profile, I want the "view source" button removed for certain users dynamically, so this needs to happen in a hook or something.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/268311/hook-editor-js-settings-alter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want a new permission so I can say that only admins can view source when using ckeditor:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function MYMODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'edit ckeditor source' => array(
      'title' => t('Edit ckeditor source'),
      'description' => t('Use the view source button on ckeditor.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then the tricky bit where we want to remove "Source" from the buttons:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_settings_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_ckeditor_settings_alter(&$settings, $conf) {
  // Only allow the View source button if the user has the permission
  if (!user_access('edit ckeditor source')) {
    // Replace 'Source' including quotes and an optional comma
    $settings['toolbar'] = preg_replace("/'Source',?/", '', $settings['toolbar']);
  }
}
```

Note that if you `print_r($settings['toolbar'])` you may think you are looking at an array, but it is a string, hence the simple string handling preg_replace above.