# hook_editor_js_settings_alter()

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I am using `hook_editor_js_settings_alter()` to disallow HTML tags in Ckeditor. It is only working in node edit form, and Ckeditor is in edit mode. Wen I preview the published page it allows the tags in my disallow custom hook.

The following code was a test to disallow `<h1>` tags with the class name *myHeader2*. If I change the class name to *myheader*, it work in edit mode and published mode. Is the class name the problem?

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

function mymodule_editor_js_settings_alter(array &$settings) {
  foreach ($settings['editor']['formats'] as $name => $value) {
    $settings['editor']['formats']['rich_text']['editorSettings']['disallowedContent'] = 'h1(myHeader2)';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to /admin/config/content/formats. For each text format, you can enable the *Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML* filter, which is configurable with the *Allowed HTML tags* text box at the bottom of the configuration form.

This is how input formats are supposed to be changed.

Comment: I am also using the allowed html in the GUI. Inside I have <h1 class>. This will allow h1 to have any class. But I also  want to disallow the h1 class "myHeader2". So I am using the hook to do it.

Comment: From the help for the *Allowed HTML tags* field:
`Each attribute may allow all values, or only allow specific values.` So, it seems like you should be able to white-list specific values this way as well.

Comment: How can I allow an h1 to have any attribute, class and style. There are too many to list right? I could do this <h1 id name href hreflang title class>  But It may still be missing some attribute. Can I do it with a wildcard like this <h1 *>  I like the way the custom hook will allow all like this h1[*]{*}(*) the 3 brackets allow all attributes, style and class names.